# Running a .NET application without .NET framework

Tags: .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running .net based application without .net framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953146/running-net-based-application-without-net-framework)

How can I run a .net application without .net framework?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953146

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.xenocode.com/ they provide a product for such