# VS2008 non.NET Application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

How can I create a VB application in VS2008 without requiring the application be run on a computer with a .NET framework in place?

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953146/running-net-based-application-without-net-framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create a non-managed VB application in VS 2008.

You would have to use C/C++ or go back to VS 6.

You can look at the question below for more information on .NET linkers. That is technically an option, but if I were starting a new application that I didn't want to depend on the .NET framework I would not use a managed language.

[Running .net based application without .net framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953146/running-net-based-application-without-net-framework/953174#953174)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use a 3rd party .NET linker, Visual Studio itself doesn't support what you're after but a number of tools allow it to be done.

A couple of tools:

- [Remotesoft Salamander .NET Linker](http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/)
- [Xenocode app virtualization](http://www.xenocode.com/)

Another, non-VS, option is to use Mono to build a "Bundle" which combines both the runtime and your application into a single executable:
[Mono:Runtime - Bundles](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime#Bundles)

Comment: My understanding is the Mono Linker is not free... and is part of the reason why MonoTouch (for building .NET applications on the iPhone) is so expensive.

Comment: @Nick: I'm not sure, but I think it's only the *Visual Studio* plugin that's not free--bundles are a part of the free package and can be built by command line.  Definately would need to double-check that though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You would need to go back to Visual Studio 6 and create a VB6 app.

Comment: VB != VB.NET, so he might as well keep using Visual Studio 2008 and write it in C++

Comment: But then it's not going to be a VB application at all...it would wind up being a native C++ app.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. VB is .net based, there isn't a non .net VB anymore.

The best you can do is include the .net redistributable with your application's installation.