# Convert a .NET WinForms Application to a binary executable

Tags: .net, windows-xp-embedded

I have a very low spec computer running XP Embedded (512Mb RAM, 512Mb HDD).  IE 8 doesn't fit on it with .NET, so I was wondering if it's possible to compile a WinForm's project to a binary executable (making it independent of the .NET framework)... for what I am doing it seems like a bit of over kill to rewrite the executable in Delphi, VB, or something similar...

Cheers,

Andrew

Comment: I'm pretty sure .NET apps only run on PCs with .NET runtimes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running .net based application without .NET Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953146/running-net-based-application-without-net-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try porting your .Net project to version 4 and then you can only install .Net 4 client profile which is of very small footprint. You will need XP Service Pack 3 installed though.

Answer (score 0):

See this too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx.

Comment: That still doesn't remove the need of the .NET runtime though. It essentially just JITs AOT.