# Run C# windows application in windows XP without installing .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running .net based application without .NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953146/running-net-based-application-without-net-framework)

Hello. Please let me know how I can run C# windows application in Windows XP without installing .NET Framework?

Comment: What? First of all, why would you want to run a C# app without having a framework installed?

Comment: Nope, not possible. Give up and learn C++ instead.

Comment: a C# app can be ran without .NET because it must not use the .NET-Framework but there wouldn't be much benefit without .NET. And if it is a .NET application then you need the .NET-Framework to run it

Comment: There are some options (see the "psossible duplicate" above), but also consider .NET client profile, Silverlight, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# apllication not handled by operating System. Its CLR(inside framework) who take care to run the C# apps and all memory management, resource allocation, de-allocation etc. It create a virtual layer over OS while runnign its application. So you must need framework(more than or equivalent to 2.0 as you said)

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

The framework and runtime need to be present for any .NET application to run.

It's like wanting a java program to run without installing a JRE.

Comment: You can create installation package with Installshield, It packs required .NEt version into setup programm.

Comment: @Anton - which will... install the framework... which is exactly what the OP doesn't want.

Comment: @user: The .NET FW 4.0 Client Profile for 32-bit machines is under 30 MB. What do you consider "big size"?

Comment: @user547706 - maybe take a look at http://www.hanselman.com/smallestdotnet/ - this site will let you know the smallest .NET download suitable for your machine. It may not be as large as you think.

Comment: @Cody - he did say he developed for .NET 2.0.

Comment: @Oded: Sure enough, he did. Looks like that got edited out of the question. Not sure why...

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. I think You have no way except installin .NET 2.0 on target machine

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you have no way to run what sits on .NET without installing the .NET Framework, this is the short answer.

Long answer is that there are some kind of softwares which pack all required dependencies ( and only the required ones ) into a bigger executable.