# how to run a winform Exe in normal Pc not having .net frame work installed

Tags: c#

I developed a winform application using C# in visual studio 2008. Now i want to run the exe on another PC which doesn't have .net framework or Visual Studio. I am sending the application using Zip via email. The second PC downloads that application and extracts into a normal folder and then it executes the exe file.
But i am getting the exception that .net frame work v 2.0 must be installed.

Can you please tell me how to run that exe without .net frame work installed?

Comment: can u plz c: possible duplicate of [Running .net based application without .NET Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953146/running-net-based-application-without-net-framework)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Amended for @Merhdad's sanity :-))

**The short answer**: You can. You shouldn't.

**The long answer**: You could technically create your own unmanaged bootstrapper that goes and download the .NET client profile redist and silently installs it using the MSI APIs, and then loads the CLR and hosts it in the process in order to execute the managed code, after which it silently uninstalls the .NET Framework from the machine.

**The Disclaimer**: I know few people that could pull that off. They would be the first to tell you not to do it.

**The alternative hack answer**: You can also use one of the tools @Mehrdad mentioned. i can't comment whether they work or not. However, you should be aware that this leaves your app linked to a specific snapshot of the .Net framework code, and for every security update you need to take, yuo have to relink and release an update of your application as well.

**The alternative open source answer**: You could ensure your WinForms app builds and runs on Mono, and deploy Mono side-by-side with the app. I've heard it supports that scenario.

**The alternative IT answer**: You could create a VM appliance with stripped down Window image that has .Net and your app only, and ship it as a single executable.

**The right answer**: Create an installer for your app that installs the .NET Framework for your customers.

Comment: The correct answer: You *can* actually just send a single, humongous twenty-something-megabyte EXE file that runs without the framework, but it's a pain and it isn't free. It's possible though; see the link in my comment.

Comment: @Mehrdad - the webpage for the first tool referenced by the link you posted returns 404. the webpage for the second tool hasn't been updated since 2008, and is still referring to their support for .Net 2.0 in future tense. (side note: it also doesn't seem to support x64, talks about precompilation to native x86 code only. that is somewhat irrelevant to this discussion, of course)

Comment: Not sure if you just tried going to the main domain site, but it returns 404 because it's evolved into [a new site/product](http://spoon.net/Studio/Features.aspx) that still seems to do what it used to do, and it also seems to claim to work for up to version 4.0. You know, I think I'll actually make this an answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done. You *must* have the .NET Framework in order to run the application.

Comment: Er... yes it can; see my link in the comment.

Comment: @Mehrdad - have you tried these tools and have a success story with a complex WinForms application deployed and running?

Comment: @Franci: I remember trying one of them a couple of years ago. Yes, it worked, but no, it wasn't a complex program, and I can't vouch that it would even work if I tried it again (I only spent a few minutes testing it, it wasn't worth the effort). Saying "this cannot be done" is a bit incorrect, though -- it might be difficult, but it's in no way impossible.

Comment: @Mehrdad - obviously anything can be done with enough time and efforts. at the end of the day shipping a single exe with a virtual appliance with a Windows VM and preinstalled .Net and the WinForms app will also work.

Comment: @Mehrdad - But unless you have positive proof these tools still exist, are actively maintained and work with .Net 4.0, you might want to avoid downvoting answers based on missing or three years old information.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Doubtful Sir. Applications created to rely on the .NET Framework _must_ have the .NET Framework. All ThinApp does is include pieces of _the .NET Framework_ in the executable. Therefore, it still requires the .NET Framework. It simply removes the requirement of installing it separately. Anyway, I wouldn't rely on a hackish program like this for anything I was hoping to make money on. Microsoft obviously won't help you out if you have issues here. Stick to installing the .NET Framework like everyone else does. The supermajority of Windows computers already have this installed anyway.

Comment: @Franci: The OP asked for version 2.0 and not 4.0, so I'm not sure what proof you need, I already said I've partially tested this. @FreeAsInBeer: You didn't say it "needs to have the .NET framework"; you said "You must have the .NET Framework *installed*", which is clearly wrong.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer: (Can't tell if you're being sarcastic after the edit or not...?) Your answer is still partially wrong, because it says "you can't", when in fact the answer is "you can". (The second part is right but doesn't answer the OP's question, since the OP was asking about having the framework *installed*.)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**! You can do this with a variety of programs, and [Spoon](http://spoon.net/Studio/Features.aspx) seems to be among the most up-to-date ones.

(Of course, this doesn't mean that you *should*, just that you *can*.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.I added a package in visual studio.I added Setup and deployment as a new project to my solution.later i added exe to that package.so if client machine runs the setup it'l create exe and can run the application successfully.

Answer (score 0):

yeah,you can do that by converting your whole application to an installer.just check it out, it will helps u a lot
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCnfGUT-K-4

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link. Imagine that page is moved to another server, or the direct link changes - future users will not be able to benefit from the answer. Take a look at [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).