# How windows based applications run without .Net framework

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

I am very much worried that i have seen many applications which i download from internet and they run without installing .net framework or java run time on windows seven, the confusion is, if it is so then in which language all these applications are built? if it is VB6 then it is very old, why latest software are using it, and did Microsoft not build Windows seven in any .net framework, for example if they build it in 3.5 then why it requires to install 3.5 .Net framework to run application.

Also let me know which db these apps usually use.

Comment: I would imagine if a program doesn't need a runtime to run under Windows that it's a fully-compiled language (not sure of the correct technical term) - like, say, a program written in C++ or C.

Comment: BTW, your question is incredibly broad (to me, at least) - especially the part about the db.  There's a very large combination of languages/databases that can be used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953146/running-net-based-application-without-net-framework

Comment: Create your WIndows app in [Delphi](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi) - it's a) much better than VB6 (always has been), and b) it compiles to native Windows code - no .NET needed....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They could be built using C or C++, or any number of other languages with no runtime libraries (or whose runtime libraries are built into the OS).  They may also just use .NET and assume that clients have the .NET framework installed.  Finally, they may actually check for the .NET framework and prompt the user to install it if it isn't there, but since you already have it installed you don't see the prompt.

As for which databases they use, it is common to see applications use SQL Server CE or Express, Berkeley DB (BDB), or any number of other small-footprint databases.  There is no clear winner in that area, just like in programming languages.

Comment: SQLite is very popular, e.g. Firefox uses it.

Comment: C++ has its variants: Win32, MFC, ATL and more. Which of them is the most commonly used by c++ windows developers?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, Windows 7 has the built-in .NET framework 3.5  So, it automatically runs the application developed in .NET, where as few earlier version of Windows OS, the user didn't have the needed framework in built.  It needs to be installed separately.