# It is posible to create a .NET application that dosen't need the .NETFramework

Tags: .net, clr, executable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running .net based application without .NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953146/running-net-based-application-without-net-framework)

Can we create an .NET application or executable on any .Net-framework, that do not require the .Net-framework for running? Maybe to embed the framework's fixtures that the application needs into the application itself? Or any way that the application host the CLR?

I made my self this question, because in this [page](http://nikosbaxevanis.com/2010/12/01/building-a-metro-ui-with-wpf/) it is written: "if it's an unmanaged application at least it hosts the CLR in it's process. (Any Windows application can host the CLR).". They are talking about a Zune application.

Comment: wierd requirement, but interesting

Comment: Why do you need such a requirement? I would think pretty much every windows computer has at least .net 2.

Comment: For instance by default Windows XP do not have the .Net-Framework by default. Windows 7 has the .Net-Framework 3.5 by default, and maybe your application is made for .Net-Framework 4.0.

Comment: Is this just curiosity?  What is the nature of the app and what kind of devices do you want to run it on?

Comment: There used to be "linkers" in the early 2000s that allowed creating an app that didn't need to have .NET installed.  They cost a lot of money and haven't been maintained.  Hard to compete with something that's free and available on almost any machine.  Hosting the CLR in an unmanaged app is something completely different.

Comment: Yes!!! It is true, each day is more difficult search if a question is already made in stack overflow. Thanks