# How to build native image for Win32 using C# and ngen.exe

Tags: c#, .net, clr, native, ngen

Is it possible to build from C# a native application like when you are using plain C/C++ and developing for Win32.

I've heard about ngen.exe and try to use it... But I don't understand what's it doing? It like it does cache the application is some system directory for rapid quick and provides to the applications some optimization, but not generating native image.

Why does it name "native generator", it doesn't produce the native output for Win32 and still requires the .net vm?

Comment: The .NET VM is used for more than just JIT. It is still needed for garbage collection, security, etc. That's why the runtime is still required.

Comment: NGen has nothing to do with this.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953146/running-net-based-application-without-net-framework .

Answer (score 3):

This just isn't what ngen is for.  ngen performs the work of the JIT compiler and saves the compiled native result in a cache.  However, the result still has dependencies on the .NET Framework.  It doesn't output a native "EXE" with no managed requirements, which I think is what you are asking for.