# Alternatives for deploying an app in a computer without the .Net Framework

Tags: c#, .net

I want to deploy an app using the .Net 4.5 version but the installed version is lower. Can I deploy without having to install the framework? Can I include the dlls I need with the execution file?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot if you compiled with .NET 4.5 you should have that particular version installed on the target machine.

Or you can use [DNX](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx) which is technically another environment and compile with that to avoid installation of .NET

Answer (score 0):

Normally, running a `.NET application` without having the required referenced assemblies installed is not possible. However, there are alternative solutions, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953146/running-net-based-application-without-net-framework).