# Distribute application with .NET and Crystal Runtime

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

My Visual Studio app requires Crystal Runtime and .NET framework. I want the user to be able to use the app without installing both of these. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

For reports, you'll almost always need to distribute the free *[Crystal Reports Viewer](http://go.sap.com/product/analytics/bi-platform/crystal-reports-viewer.html)*.

For publishing .NET apps without a .NET dependency, you'll want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953146/running-net-based-application-without-net-framework) for a *.NET Linker*. Although it's worth noting that the .NET framework is rather easy to install and commonplace enough where having the end user install it might be a better option.